# How to exclude unmanaged resources from Compile scope only (not from Test)

Tags: scala, testing, settings, sbt, unmanagedresources

In one of my sub projects, I am trying to exclude *.conf and *.groovy files from my list of unmanaged resources:

```
excludeFilter in Compile in unmanagedResources  := "*.conf" || "*.groovy"
```

Now, this works but has the unintended effect of removing the *.conf files from Test.
I tried to add the following includeFilter setting :

```
includeFilter in Test in unmanagedResources := "*.conf"
```

However, this does not work.
I figure that there is a relationship between Test and Compile that may be causing this issue.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here and you've identified the main one, which is the relationship between Test and Compile.  The other is that a file must both be included by `includeFilter` and not be excluded by `excludeFilter`.

Test gets its settings from Compile if none are specified for Test explicitly.  When you define `excludeFilter in Compile`, it applies to Test as well.  So, you can define `excludeFilter in Test` to be the default, which is to ignore hidden files:

```
excludeFilter in Test := HiddenFileFilter
```

(Or, you can use `NoFilter` to not have any exclusions.)